# Flask returning '(Decimal(&#39;0.82483097725875845114&#39;),),' from a flask_sqlalchemy query. How to clean up?

Tags: postgresql, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm useing Postgres as my backend. I've set the values to Numeric, fwiw.

My flask route:

```
@app.route('/doughnut_chart')
def doughnut_chart():

    values = []
    labels =['good', 'mediocre','bad']
    colors = ['rgba(0, 153, 0, 0.1)', 'rgba(0,153,153,0.1)','rgba(102,153,51,0.1)']

    good_high = db.session.query(func.sum(Jf_Q1.highwellbeing)/func.sum(Jf_Q1.good_job)).\
        filter(Jf_Q1.working==1).filter(Jf_Q1.good_job==1)

    good_mod = db.session.query(func.sum(Jf_Q1.moderatewellbeing)/func.sum(Jf_Q1.good_job)).\
        filter(Jf_Q1.working==1).filter(Jf_Q1.good_job==1)

    good_low = db.session.query(func.sum(Jf_Q1.lowwellbeing)/func.sum(Jf_Q1.good_job)).\
        filter(Jf_Q1.working==1).filter(Jf_Q1.good_job==1)


    values.append(str(good_high[0]))
    values.append(str(good_mod[0]))
    values.append(str(good_low[0]))
    #values = [10,60,30]
    #values = [0.82483097725875845114*100,0.14935464044253226798*100,0.01966810079901659496*100]

    return render_template('results.html', values=values,labels=labels, colors=colors)
```

My script in my html page:

```
  datasets:
                    //[{ data : {{values | safe}},
                    [{ data: 
                      [
                    {% for value in values  %}
                         {{ value | tojson }},
                    {% endfor %}
                      ],
```

In Chrome's inspector I'm seeing:

```
       datasets: [{
              data : [
                               (Decimal(&#39;0.82483097725875845114&#39;),),
                                (Decimal(&#39;0.14935464044253226798&#39;),),
                                 (Decimal(&#39;0.01966810079901659496&#39;),),
                            ],
```

I've tried 'tojson' and 'safe' in my flask for loop, but I can' seem to get just the values such as:

```
             data : [
                               0.82483097725875845114,
                               0.14935464044253226798,
                               0.01966810079901659496,
                            ],
```

I've read using .scalar() in my flask_alchemy queries but that tossed multiple errors

Thank you very much!

Comment: Does this get you anywhere: `{{ "%.2f"|format(value|float) }}`?

Comment: Chrome inspector is showing the values in the list now as 0.00, 0.00, 0.00

Comment: At least the 'decimial(' part is gone :) Thanks for your help

Comment: Huh, that surprises me haha. I'll think more about this.

Comment: Thanks Bernie. I tried to do something like values.append(str(good_low[0].strip())) but that bombed out

Comment: I hacked a solution

Comment: def postprocessor(result):
        return result.split('(')[2].strip('),')

Comment: Nice work. It seems like a lot of hoops to jump through for something simple...